# Grease Pencil Not Working Correctly

Tags: color, grease-pencil, 2d

I'm using Blender 9.3 on a Microsoft Surface LTE.

When I try to use grease pencil in "general" it just won't work at all.

When I use grease pencil in 2D animation, it shows up as a dulled color of the color chosen in materials.

I've searched high and low online and none of the solutions I've found have worked for me. Is it just the tablet I'm using? Please HALP!!!

Comment: My friend @maddyballs is having the same issue/symptoms, also on 2.93.1 / Windows (and doesn't have enough reputation to comment. Switching render engines as per https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-you-get-grease-pencil-working-in-2-8-build/691464 does not help.

Comment: Grease pencil works for us in Blender 2.79 as well as 2.83.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I eventually just settled to download a slightly older version. Here's the [link for 2.83][1]

It's from this https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.83/ on the blender website.

Now my grease pencil works just fine. Only if your up for going a little back I guess.
[1]: https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.83/blender-2.83.0-windows64.msi